# How to turn on Screen Recording in MTM?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, screen-capture, microsoft-test-manager, exploratory

MTM VISUAL STUDIO 2012

When I start exploratory testing in MTM , a message pops up and says "Screen Recording is disabled".

Screen recording is only unavailable when I try to do Exploratory Testing.

How do I turn on the Screen Recording in Exploratory Testing ?

Answer (score 1):

Select **Test** tab in **Testing Center** and go to **Do Exploratory Testing**.

Select **Explore with options** from the dropdown and select a test setting for which Screen Recording is enabled.

Comment: It can now record the actions but the when i create a bug from there steps are not available and also video recording is not re playable.

Comment: i checked for both steps in bug and recording, i got both working fine. You can replay the video only after ending the exploratory test session.

if you found answer to your question helpful please accept it as answer